# Absolute positioning of child views in a Famo.us ScrollView

Tags: famo.us

I've a ScrollView of images, while clicking on an image (read imageSurface), I would like that one to smoothy scale to an absolute location of the screen (for example a fullscreen) this independently of the scroll state. [Here is an example of a similar behaviour](http://codepen.io/befamous/pen/kbxnH).

In my understanding, I should find a way to retrieve the current imageSurface location and apply a modifier with an opposite location in order to virtually detach the surface from the ScrollView. Then I might apply the modifier I would like (for example a full screen modifier).

Another option would be to override the ScrollView's `render()` function but I'm not sure it is a good/safe idea.

Removing the image from the sequence to quickly add it somewhere else but attached to another modifier (not in the scrollview) is also an alternative but I fear having glitches and not being able to fade it back to the sequence correctly.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same with a view but when / if I figure it out I'll post it. I don't feel like the click event is passing through enough information. I've thought about just animating the view in to the full size of the screen while scrolling the view to place it in the center. It's not the look I'm going for but it may have to do.

Comment: The ScrollView being a ViewSequence behind, it's purpose is to provide a modifier (i.e. a transformation) to each of it's content. By overriding the render function customising the transform for a selected item should do it. This said, I basically would like to avoid overriding the private render method of the ScrollView where this might broke in a further Famo.us update